# onClick fires multiple time in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-handling, dom-events

I have following component.

```
import React from 'react'
import Profile from './Profile'

import Messages from './Messages'
class ContactContent extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      message: ''
    }
    this.handleOnClick = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      console.log('send message called')
    //   this.props.onSendMessage(this.state.message)
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { id, name, profile, messages } = this.props.user
    return (
      <div className='content'>
        <Profile
          name={id}
          profile={profile}
        />
        <Messages
          messages={messages}
        />
        <div className='message-input'>
          <div className='wrap'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Write your message...' onChange={(e) => this.setState({ message: e.target.value })} />
            {/* <i className="fa fa-paperclip attachment" aria-hidden="true"></i> */}
            <button className='' onClick={this.handleOnClick}><i className='fa fa-paper-plane' aria-hidden='true' /></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ContactContent
```

when I click on button onclick is called which triggers handleonclick function. but handleonclick is being called like infinit time. this is a weird behavior I have seen this first time any idea what I have done wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with you code

Comment: I figured it out there was external javascript file which was creating issue. Thanks anyway @LucaFabbri

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it there was an external javascript file which was creating this issue. Nothing is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are calling the **handleOnClick** each time on page load/render load here
So without making this, or to avoid multiple call try to use:

> fat arrow call of that function on onClick event.

```
<button className='' onClick={(e) => this.handleOnClick(e)}><i className='fa fa-paper-plane' aria-hidden='true' /></button>
```

Comment: I disagree. I think using fat arrow is not a good approach here because whenever component renders it creates a new anonymous function which is an overhead we can avoid this by passing reference of this.handleOnClick to onClick. What's you thought?

Comment: Firstly you declare your handler function in constructor call.

And as told earlier with arrow function, your function will not call till handler makes event on it... So this is correct way.